# A/C units sweating in the attic

Tags: hvac

I have 2 Heil 19 SEAR units that are sweating tons of water in the pan. They are V speed units that can regulate the humidity in the house to 50 t0 55. The house is a foam house which has been sealed and resealed after a smoke test.

Humidity in the attic is 72 with a temp of 76. I am told that this is too close to the dew point and need to plug the holes. We plugged a 4" bath vent to the outside that had been disconnected and small leaks around a dormer. The house is on the Gulf coast.  I still have sweating units and some ducts that are moist.

There are returns holes in the plenum and a 4" discharge in the attic. The holes and discharge were attempts to solve the humidity issues.They helped some but did not correct the problem.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused. Is your attic a sealed and conditioned space?

Comment: It is sealed. It is like an Igloo ice chest. 6 to 8" an the bottom of the roof deck, 6' in the wall and 3" on the bottom. House is elevated 12 feet from grade.

Comment: MRoll with a humidity of 72 (high) it won’t take much to create condensate. Humidifiers and cooling coils for AC systems do this and this is why they have galvanized drip pans to extend their service life. The drip pan should be tilted to a drain or pump that pushes the water outside or into a drain.  If you want to eliminate any moisture turn the units off. This will stop any dehumidification and any cooling but to eliminate the moisture from the coils that is your only option. I tried to explain this I’m my answer.

Comment: A house near me was constructed with a sealed space between the 2nd floor ceiling and the roof. Spray foam was applied to the underside of the roof decking. I talked with the builder but I  cannot remember if this spray foam was open cell or closed cell. I will try to get the builder's name.

Answer (score 2):

Sweating or normal condensate is a byproduct of air conditioning. Dripping in the pan and will continue to do so until the humidity is 20-30 points lower then it will slow but continue to drip (that’s why there is a pan to catch the water or condensate)
Once the water is caught it can be pumped or piped out of the home.
If you have sweating on the outside of the unit you are lucky your pan catches it. Insulating that metal surface can reduce or even eliminate sheet metal sweating when sealed with insulation.

So sealing is a start but insulating the ductwork Will be needed because as long as there is cold metal in a high humid area it will sweat.

If you have a glass of ice water is it sweating? Your metal parts are the same.

Comment: Check the draining regularly.+1

Comment: The units have dehumidifiers built in. We tried raising the temp in the conditioned attic space but it did not make a difference. if i pass my hand under the unit, i will have more than just a wet hand. I am scared it will get into the duct system and rust out the bottom of the unit. Would you recommend a stand alone dehumidifier?

Comment: @MRoll the dehumidifier takes water vapor from the air and condenses it into liquid water. That liquid water has to go somewhere, so it's dripping into the pan. Does your pan drain into your DWV system to minimize the chance of overflow, or is it just a catch pan?

Comment: That's absolutely right.  *Some part* of an air conditioning plant needs to be colder than ambient, obviously! That part will attract condensation.  I'm presuming the evaporators and air handlers are somewhere else like in your basement (gulf coast? maybe not).  If the evaporators are *here*, then ***of course they  make condensation***.

Answer (score 0):

### Air contains water. Warm air can contain more water than cool.

True fact.  Air wants to contain moisture and water will directly evaporate into the air wherever possible. If you ever breathe air that doesn't contain water, *you know it immediately* because it steals moisture out of your mouth, throat and lungs.  Aircraft pressurization is somewhat like that.

How much water can air possibly hold?  **That depends a great deal on the temperature**. Warm air can hold *much* more water than cool air.  And that is why we express humidity in terms of "Relative Humidity" instead of an absolute unit like grams per litre.  RH is the percentage of water in the air compared to the maximum *at that temperature*.

### When you chill air, the water falls out.

That is why an ice cold glass will have condensation. It is not leaking through the glass. The air that is very close to the glass is being chilled by the glass; when its temperature falls, it cannot hold as much water.  The water has to come out.  So the water grabs onto the nearest surface, and there you are.

As you can guess, an air conditioning system works by passing warm air through a chiller.  This transfers heat (makes the air cold).  **What happens when you make air cold?  Bingo.  You reduce its capacity to hold water.  The water must fall out of it.**

That is why ever air conditioning unit, every single one, that has ever been made, needs to contend with **condensation** on its evaporator coils.  In massive quantity.  Like, a 1/2" drain line is not excessive.

That drain line has to go somewhere, noting that the condensate can be a bit corrosive, since it is not mineralized like normal tap water is.  It wants to be mineralized and will suck minerals out of piping.   It's not grey water and can simply be overboarded.

Aside from the evaporator, other parts of the machine may also be cooler than ambient.  Those too will tend to collect condensation, especially if they are poorly insulated or the insulation has been defeated by a careless maintainer.

Comment: Thanks for the research.  My units have 2 drains. one that goes to the sewer system and the other is the overflow drain pan. the pan has a 1'' drain pipe that drips infront of a window. The overflow is  one that  catches the condensation that occurs in the attic on the outside of the unit. I have another home 50 miles inland that never has water in the pan. Different mfgs. The beach home also has moisture on the bottom of the plenum that drips on the sheetrock ceiling. I hate to have a bigger pan made because it would be tough installing at this point. Thanks again for considering my problem.

Comment: @MRoll  when the pan has water in it it tells us that the primary drain is not functioning properly.

Comment: A/C man is due out Monday. Will have him open the unit and check the primary drain but i think the unit is condensation on the outside and not leaking from the inside. Both units are doing the same thing. They are 5T and a 4T , 5 speed (V) units.

Comment: @MRoll  That's kinda my core point. A/C units must necessarily have parts in them which are cooler than ambient (other than the evaporator). One hopes they're well insulated, but if they're not, condensate will form on them.  It might be someone serviced something and pulled out the insulation because it was in the way, and thought it trivial and did not reinstall it.

Comment: All good points. A/C man stood me up. I am getting another heat load run on the house. A consultant told me that 9 tons of A/C is too much for a 4,ooo sq ft  foam house. A/C man says the units are variable speed and the tonnage is OK. Who is right?